# Laravel Socialite broken after moving from local environment

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, laravel-socialite

I'm stuck with a real annoying problem. I did some experimenting with Laravel inside a virtual box and now I felt like my application was ready to go live on my server. Therefore I uploaded the whole project to my server and gave permissions to storage and bootstrap/cache folder.

I'm using Socialite for Twitch to authenticate users. I added all required stuff like (key, secret and NEW redirect url) to the .env file and I also changed the redirect url within my twitch application settings. For whatever reason I'm not able to login anymore. I always get the following error.

```
(1|1) InvalidStateException
in AbstractProvider.php (line 32)
at AbstractProvider->user()
in TwitchAuthController.php (line 34)
at TwitchAuthController->handleProviderCallback()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(TwitchAuthController), 'handleProviderCallback'), array())
in Controller.php (line 55)
```

TwitchAuthController.php line 34 looks like this, that's where all bad things start to happen ;P

```
$user = Socialite::driver('twitch')->user();
```

I still have the project on my virtual box from where I devolop it and sync it with my "real" server, so this means both projects (virtual box and server) are exactly the same. As soon as I change the redirect url in my .env file and in twitch settings back to the virtual box ip, login works fine again. I have no idea why it works flawless there but not when I adjust settings for my server.

Probably it has something todo with the "SESSION_DOMAIN" env.

I changed that one to:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=http://example.com
```

It still got the same error, so I changed back the redirect URL to:

```
TWITCH_REDIRECT_URI=http://1.2.3.4/twitch/callback
```

and also changed the URL on the twitch api site itself. After that I tried and I got the same error that I'm getting on my live production webserver. So I removed the SESSION_DOMAIN completly from .env and it started to work again on my virtual box. Somehow this seems to be session related I guess. Still have no idea why the exact same clone on my virtual box works perfectly while it's not working on my live web server eventhough the code is exactly the same, only difference is the redirect url which I have to adjust for each setup.

Nobody any idea ?

Best

Best Tom

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don`t change Redirect URL in Twitch Application config, check this image.
[image: screen]

Comment: Hi, I did that. That's what I meant by "...also changed the URL on the twitch api site itself."

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it seems that the query string is not being passed in my live environment. I added Request to my callback handler and printed the result with `dd($request`).

First example is when I adjusted settings (.env file twitch redirect url + twich api site itself) to the ip of my virtual box where 1 clone is running right now.

```
+server: ServerBag {#42 ▼
    #parameters: array:35 [▼
      "USER" => "www-data"
      "HOME" => "/var/www"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "XSRF-TOKEN=blahhhblaaaaah ▶"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, sdch"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://1.1.1.1/"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
      "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "1.1.1.1"
      "REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "_"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "80"
      "SERVER_ADDR" => "192.168.1.10"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "65268"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "1.1.1.1"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "nginx/1.10.0"
      "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
      "REQUEST_SCHEME" => "http"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/home/tom/site/public"
      "DOCUMENT_URI" => "/index.php"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/twitch/callback?code=somecode12345&scope=user_read+user_subscriptions&state=somestate121411"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => ""
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => ""
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
      "QUERY_STRING" => "code=somecode12345&scope=user_read+user_subscriptions&state=somestate121411"
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "/home/tom/site/public/index.php"
      "PATH_INFO" => ""
      "FCGI_ROLE" => "RESPONDER"
      "PHP_SELF" => "/index.php"
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1496424273.7195
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1496424273
    ]
```

This here is the result, when I change url settings for live environment on my server ((.env file twitch redirect url + twich api site itself)

```
+server: ServerBag {#42 ▼
    #parameters: array:35 [▼
      "USER" => "www-data"
      "HOME" => "/var/www"
      "HTTP_COOKIE" => "sometoken17414115 ▶"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" => "en-US,en;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" => "gzip, deflate, sdch"
      "HTTP_REFERER" => "http://example.com/"
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
      "HTTP_USER_AGENT" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
      "HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS" => "1"
      "HTTP_CONNECTION" => "keep-alive"
      "HTTP_HOST" => "example.com"
      "REDIRECT_STATUS" => "200"
      "SERVER_NAME" => "example.com"
      "SERVER_PORT" => "80"
      "SERVER_ADDR" => "3.3.3.3"
      "REMOTE_PORT" => "51008"
      "REMOTE_ADDR" => "9.9.9.9"
      "SERVER_SOFTWARE" => "nginx/1.10.0"
      "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" => "CGI/1.1"
      "REQUEST_SCHEME" => "http"
      "SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1"
      "DOCUMENT_ROOT" => "/var/www/site/public"
      "DOCUMENT_URI" => "/index.php"
      "REQUEST_URI" => "/twitch/callback?code=somecode12345&scope=user_read+user_subscriptions&state=somestate121411"
      "SCRIPT_NAME" => "/index.php"
      "CONTENT_LENGTH" => ""
      "CONTENT_TYPE" => ""
      "REQUEST_METHOD" => "GET"
      "QUERY_STRING" => ""
      "SCRIPT_FILENAME" => "/var/www/site/public/index.php"
      "PATH_INFO" => ""
      "FCGI_ROLE" => "RESPONDER"
      "PHP_SELF" => ""
      "REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT" => 1496425556.5687
      "REQUEST_TIME" => 1496425556
    ]
```

There are 2 differences I can see in this result. First of all `QUERY_STRING` is empty eventhough the address I get this results from looks like this:

```
http://example.com/twitch/callback?code=n60im8s9c7cmvffn705jwzjbtx76ea&scope=user_read+user_subscriptions&state=8AcRvwvRcupj6lrJmYYvM6Q70A9OZEBRIRGXiQxb
```

And `PHP_SELF` is also empty while in my working example (on virtual box system) shows `index.php` as result.

I'm now pretty much stuck for 24 hours and still can't figure it out eventhough I found this details.

Answer (score 0):

Wow I'm so stupid. I wasted countless hours in the last 24 hours because I tought it had something to do with the migration from a local environment to my server. At first I was thinking about a permission/session problem or whatever. After doing some research on the QUERY_STRING issue that I found in the last hour I checked my webserver config once over again. Turns out that I'm just stupid. Even though I could swear that I simply copied the nginx php-fpm settings from my dev environment the mistake was right there.

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string; # Looked like this
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; # Should have been this...
```

So all of this was just a simple question mark missing.... I feel so bad right now.

Still wondering why everything else worked perfectly fine like routes to news, edit news and so one. I tought all of this is also using the QUERY_STRING parameter.